# another way to load sprites in pixi

Tags: pixi.js

As `PIXI.add("file.json")` can load sprite/texture from a packed png file.

but the JSON file is not allowed in wechat game.

I' tried to write the JSON into js and imported it but it not work.

how to load the JSON file without the .json extensions?

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to resolve it.

I made a rectangle list of each sprite and specified it to `PIXI.Texture.frame` and created a new sprite then I can use it well.

What's more, you need to use `clone()` function to clone a texture to create the new sprite or it will change the original texture. All sprites you created will use the same texture.